# Why doesn't s3fs work like a normal file system with Apache MINA SSHD?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, sftp, mina, sshd

So I'm trying to create a Java SFTP server which acts as a front end for Apache S3 buckets.  You connect via SFTP and manage S3 files in buckets like they were files on the SFTP server.

I've used [Apache MINA](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/) (v1.2.0) as the SFTP server, which works fine using an `SftpSubsystemFactory` and default `FileSystemFactory` (providing the local filesystem).
I've chosen [Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2)(v1.3.0) as the `FileSystem`, which uses the [Apache AWS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) and seems to be the best option out there

```
public class S3FileSystemFactory implements FileSystemFactory {
    private URI uri = URI.create("localhost");

    public S3FileSystemFactory(URI uri){
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public FileSystem createFileSystem(Session session) throws IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        FileSystem s3FileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, new HashMap<String, Object>(), classLoader);
        return s3FileSystem;
    }
}
```

I'm just setting this as the `FileSystemFactory` for MINA

```
SshServer sshd = SshServer.setUpDefaultServer();
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(buildHostKeyProviderFromFile(hostKeyType));
sshd.setPasswordAuthenticator(createPasswordAuthenticator());
sshd.setPublickeyAuthenticator(AcceptAllPublickeyAuthenticator.INSTANCE);
sshd.setSubsystemFactories(createSubsystemFactories());
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(createFileSystemFactory());

URI uri = URI.create("s3:///s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket"); 
FileSystemFactory s3FileSystemFactory = new S3FileSystemFactory(uri);
sshd.setFileSystemFactory(s3FileSystemFactory);
```

I can connect to this server with FileZilla/Command Line but it auto connects to the `ImageTransfer` bucket (not `my_bucket`).  I can navigate to other buckets, even sub buckets but can't display the contents, everything just looks like an empty directory.

This can be done via the `FileSystem` [I'm using](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2) as I can list directory contents, like so

```
    Path p = s3FileSystem.getPath("/my_bucket");
    String contents = "";
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(p, "*")) {
        for (Path file : stream) {
            contents += "\n \t - " + file.getFileName();
        }
    } catch (IOException | DirectoryIteratorException x) {}
```

I've been looking through the s3fs, MINA and AWS code (as the documentation is very limited) but can't pinpoint the source of this problem.  Can anyone shed any light on what I'm doing wrong?

**Logging**

With logging for all libraries switched on, I get only one issue I can see

```
"HEAD
application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Fri, 20 May 2016 09:58:07 GMT
/MYURL/."
2016-05-20 10:58:07.240 DEBUG 13323 --- [system-thread-1] c.a.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient       : Stale connection check
2016-05-20 10:58:07.243 DEBUG 13323 --- [system-thread-1] c.a.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient       : Attempt 1 to execute request
2016-05-20 10:58:07.434 DEBUG 13323 --- [system-thread-1] c.a.http.impl.client.SdkHttpClient       : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2016-05-20 10:58:07.435 DEBUG 13323 --- [system-thread-1] com.amazonaws.request                    : Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Not Found (Service: null; Status Code: 404; Error Code: 404 Not Found; Request ID: MYREQID), S3 Extended Request ID: MYEXTREQID
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is twofold.

Firstly, Apache MINA SSHD [requires](https://github.com/apache/mina-sshd/blob/bf0187dad36289a6ae6518173a6e310abe4105e4/sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/server/subsystem/sftp/SftpSubsystem.java#L267) the `permission` attribute be present for any `FileSystem` it uses, which is strange as that's a POSIX specific attribute so obviously [Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2) hasn't provided it.

Secondly, Apache MINA SSHD calls (and requires) an unimplemented method in [S3FileSystemProvider](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/upplication/s3fs/S3FileSystemProvider.java) that get's a `FileChannel`

```
public FileChannel newFileChannel(Path path,
                                  Set<? extends OpenOption> options,
                                  FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
```

A hacky solution is just to hard-code POSIX read/write permissions into S3 attributes returned and create a `S3FileChannel` that simply calls the methods on the existing [S3SeekableByteChannel](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2/blob/master/src/main/java/com/upplication/s3fs/S3SeekableByteChannel.java).
 That's the best solution I can come up with for now.

Answer (score 1):

We forked the [Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2](https://github.com/Upplication/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2) and implemented missing things so that the S3 FileSystem works with Apache Mina SFTP.

You can find the repo [here](https://github.com/jcustovic/Amazon-S3-FileSystem-NIO2/tree/file-channel-impl) and build it locally with maven.

How we use it in MINA is like this:

```
public FileSystemFactory createFileSystemFactory(String bucketName) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(new URI("s3:///"), env, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
    String bucketPath = fileSystem.getPath("/" + bucketName);

    return new VirtualFileSystemFactory(bucketPath);
}
```

Comment: I came across your fork. Do you have an issue tracke for it? What license is it under (in some places, it say it's under MIT and in others -- Apahe 2.0. It might be a good idea to add a `LICENSE.md` file and clarify. Is the project still being actively developed?